# Cloud Function Triggered by Pubsub

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

```
import base64
import logging

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Pub/Sub.
    Args:
         event (dict):  The dictionary with data specific to this type of
         event. The `data` field contains the PubsubMessage message. The
         `attributes` field will contain custom attributes if there are any.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): The Cloud Functions event
         metadata. The `event_id` field contains the Pub/Sub message ID. The
         `timestamp` field contains the publish time.
    """
    import base64
    import time
    import json
    import requests
    print(event)

    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))

    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print(name)
    print(type(name))    
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
    
    
    payload = json.loads(name)
    logging.debug(payload)
```

I was trying to execute this is cloud function but I am getting an error, which is probably because of json.loads(). How can I get the payload as Json

**Error:**

```
line 32, in hello_pubsub payload = json.loads(name) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What was the value of "name" when the error is produced?

Comment: value of name= b'{"abc":"123456","Def":"udebj"}



type of name= <class 'str'> @Kolban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the Issue by Changing encoding.
I was encoding string data, changed it to encode json data and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.
Please try to publish the message directly to topic on UI.
I tried with following message and it gave the output
`{"abc":"123456","Def":"udebj"}`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vikram I am publishing the msg using my UI, But unlike you I am receiving ```b'{"abc":"123456","Def":"udebj"}``` as output. And json.loads() throws the decode error

Comment: Can you help share the cloud function that you have written

Comment: If you are using python3.8 then add requests library in requirements.txt
If you are using python3.7, no changes are required.

Comment: can you share your logs screenshot and input data to pubsub topic

Comment: input data: {"abc":"def"}